# How can I be notified of angular setting the value of an input field via ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5zk1om2/1/).

I've got a simple directive in which I just log the value of the checkbox that it's added to:

```
myApp.directive('myCheckBox', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('directive linking function, checked = ', element[0].checked);

        // not triggered on startup
        element.bind('change', function (event) {
            console.log('onChange, checked = ', element[0].checked);
        });

    }
});
```

This checkbox's value is bound to a property in the enclosing Controller:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">Boolean1:
        <input my-check-box type="checkbox" ng-model="settings.boolean1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.settings = {
        boolean1: true
    }
}]);
```

The problem is I can't find a way to find out (in the directive) what the "initial" value (i.e. the value that the Controller sets it to) is.

If you view the console, you'll see that the initial log statement reports it as false (I'm not exactly sure why, but I guess this is executed before Angular's data binding takes place - is there a better way to architect this so that's not the case?).  If you manually toggle the value, then the change event is fired.  But it's not fired on startup, so I don't know how to get the value.

How can I simply get the value (that is set via ng-model) on startup, or how can I listen for that change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is `$watch` the `ngModel` attached to the element. When you watch a variable, you can see the old and new values.

```
myApp.directive('myCheckBox', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            console.log('directive linking function, checked = ', element[0].checked);

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log(newValue, oldValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**[JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/12hdma2L/)**

Comment: Thank you!  At first I missed the 'require' field, but this works well.  Of course the first function is executing all the time, but that's to be expected.